# Porting duktape, getting duk_create_heap error during JS compilation of builtin initjs

Tags: duktape

This question might be too detailed for this forum, but I could not find a mailing list for duktape. Maybe this question will be useful for others trying to get duktape running on more obscure hardware.

I am trying to get duktape to work on an old ColdFire CPU, using an OLD gcc compiler (2.95.3). The board has limited resources (flash/RAM) but I seem to have enough of both. I must live with the old compiler.

I believe the duk_config.h is calculating the right options regarding endianness, etc. I am using a number of the duktape options to reduce code and data size. I have successfully used the same configuration on 64 and 32 bit Ubuntu and it works fine.

The "properties string" that is formed and set in duk_hthread_create_builtin_objects() is:
"bb u pnRHSBOL p2 a8 generic linux gcc" which seems correct (not sure of the effect of the "generic" tag for architecture).

I am getting a failure when calling duk_create_heap(). I have isolated the problem to a what I believe is a JS compile error related to duk_initjs. If I undef DUK_USE_BUILTIN_INITJS, initialization works. The error is a syntax error (not sure where yet). By running "strings" on my executable, I can see that the javascript program source string is there. As a side issue, when this error occurs, the longjmp doesn't work (setjmp never called?) so my fatal handler gets called, but I don't care about for now.

I thought it might be my small C stack (as it appears the js compiler uses recursion) but making the stack much larger didn't help.

I am starting to dig into the JS compiler, but this must be an issue with the architecture or my environment. Any suggestions appreciated!

EDIT: I just now noticed a post of a similar issue, and there was a request to repeat with "-DDUK_OPT_DEBUG -DDUK_OPT_DPRINT -DDUK_OPT_ASSERTIONS -DDUK_OPT_SELF_TESTS"  I will try to use these options (if possible, I am very close to a relocation limit on my executable).

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in 1.4.0 release (https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/pull/550) which caused duk_config.h to incorrectly end up with an unpacked value representation even when the architecture supported packed representation. This might be an issue in your case - try adding and explicit -DDUK_OPT_PACKED_TVAL (which forces Duktape to use packed representation) to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!